# Searching for numbers in a comma separated string in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

df1:

```
id, Name, Lastname, Account, ProofID1, ProofID2, transaction_codes_history
1,  ab1,  dc1,      312,     1224,     111,      0, 1.3, 2.1, 3, 4.1, 9.1, 1.1, 7.2
2,  ab2,  dc2,      434,     1225,     112,      0, 1.2, 2.1, 1.4, 3, 4.4, 12.2
3,  ab3,  dc3,      578,     1226,     111,      0, 1.2, 2.1, 1.4, 3, 4.2, 12.1
4,  ab4,  dc4,      624,     1227,     112,      0, 1.1, 7.2
5,  ab5,  dc5,      684,     1228,     113,      0, 1.3, 2.1, 3, 9.2, 11.2
```

I am trying to copy specific columns according to their **transaction_codes_history**.

If **transaction_codes_history** contains at least `4.1` or `7.2` or `1.1`, then we will copy those columns into a dataframe.

**transaction_codes_history** is a comma separated string of float numbers.

Expected output:

```
Name, Account, ProofID1, ProofID2
ab1,  312,     1224,     111     
ab3,  578,     1225,     111       
ab4,  624,     1227,     112
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating additionnal columns like:

```
df["to_keep"] = df["transaction_codes_history"].str.contains("1.1|4.1|7.2", regex=True)
```

then you can keep only the rows you want :

```
df[df["to_keep"]][["id", "Name", "Lastname", "Account"]]
```

I hope it helps,
Nicolas

Comment: if i take x=df.iloc[0]['transaction_codes_history'], x is of type str, ie (0, 1.3, 2.1, 3, 4.1, 9.1, 1.1, 7.2), now if i want to know that x has 4.1 or not, how do I find it out??

Comment: You can create one column by value with str.contains for your dataframe. However, in your specific case, you can split x and parse it with `x = [float(k) for k in x.split(",")]`. After you can do a simple if 4.1 in x (btw you should be able to do it on the string but the performance may be slower)